# setSupportActionBar not working FragmentActivity

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, toolbar

I'm trying to create a custom `Toolbar` on my `FragmentActivity` but at the time I launch the app it crashes on this lane :

`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

I have no more code, since I started to add this `Toolbar` so I have this on my `MainActivity`

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //LogCat is pointing this
    }
}
```

My `Toolbar` code is :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    iosched:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    iosched:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    iosched:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
    iosched:contentInsetStart="?actionBarInsetStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you got any solution.. I am also facing same issue and cann't change my activity to extend FragmentActivity. Please help if your problem got resolved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong?

You are extending `FragmentActivity` and this is the problem....

You should change it to `AppCompatActivity`

Your `MainActivity` should look like this : `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Also don't forget to import its libraries :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: That was my error... I had compiled those libraries but I wasn't using `AppCompatActivity` thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the AppcompatActivity:

```
MainActivity extends AppcompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather late, but for the sake of those who really want to use FragmentActivity, you can add something like:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getApplicationContext()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

for Fragment:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Hope this is the answer that you're looking for.